# Calling class functions that use character arrays (C++)

Tags: c++, function, class, object, serialization

I mostly work with C and have not used classes in quite a while. I am trying to use some class functions that someone else has created but I cannot get the deserialize() function to work. I understand what it does, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to call this function. I have provided functions and how I am trying to call them below.

```
//Creates a packet 
packet::packet(int t, int s, int l, char * d){
    type = t;
    seqnum = s;
    length = l;
    data = d;
}
// This function serializes the data such that type, seqnum, length, and data values are placed 
// in a char array, spacket, and separated by a single space; that is, spacket contains the serialized data
void packet::serialize(char * spacket){
        cout << "data: " << endl << endl;
    sprintf (spacket, "%d %d %d %s", type, seqnum, length, data);   
}

// This function deserializes a char array, spacket, which is the result of a call to serialize
void packet::deserialize(char * spacket){
    char * itr;
    itr = strtok(spacket," ");
    char * null_end;

    this->type = strtol(itr, &null_end, 10);

    itr = strtok(NULL, " ");
    this->seqnum = strtol (itr, &null_end, 10);

    itr = strtok(NULL, " ");
    this->length = strtol (itr, &null_end, 10);

    if(this->length == 0){
        data = NULL;
    }
    else{
        itr = strtok(NULL, ""); 
        for(int i=0; i < this->length; i++){ // copy data into char array
            this->data[i] = itr[i];
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how I am trying to get this to work:

```
packet *test = new packet(1, 4, 4, message); //message is a *char with the data
test->serialize(sendbuf);          //this works correctly
packet *test2 = new packet(0,0,0, NULL);  //I am not sure if I need to be creating a new packet for the deserialized information to get placed into
test->deserialize(sendbuf);    //results in a segmentation fault currently
```

I just don't understand how to call deserialize(), I have created a packet and serialized it and that part works fine, but I don't understand how to reverse it. Do I need to create an empty packet object first? If so, how? I have tried doing that multiple ways but I cannot get it to work. I know this is very basic but like I said, I have not worked with classes in a couple of years. It took me quite a while just to get serialize to work but I have tried everything I can think of for deserialize and am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Pongjazzle,

I agree with Sam that the class design needed refinement. However, I think you can figure it out. Perhaps, you might want to do it this way to test your code, assuming sendbuf can hold all the serialized packet data.

```
packet *test = new packet(1, 4, 4, message);
test->serialize(sendbuf);

packet *test2 = new packet(0,0,0, NULL); // results in a segmentation fault currently (which is expected as the attempts to access a location referred to by a null pointer in this->data (i.e., NULL based on the object instantiation code)
test->deserialize(sendbuf);
```

Change it to:

```
packet *test2 = new packet(0,0,0, newmessage); // assign a valid buffer
test2->deserialize(sendbuf);  // Now fill's in the values and buffer from serialized content.
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you. I understand now that I was creating a packet but not giving it a buffer to work with.

Answer (score 1):

The class you're using is not designed very well.

For starters, the `serialize()` function takes a pointer to an output buffer, without having any means to specify the size of the buffer. It takes it on faith that the buffer is going to be big enough for the "serialized" data. If it's not, it will happy scribble over random memory.

Then, `deserialize()` is also impressive. For starters, no self-respecting deserializer requires a mutable pointer to the data being deserialized. A deserializer should only require a constant, or a read-only pointer.

Of course, the reason that this `deserialize()` wants a mutable buffer is because it scribbles over, and overwrites via `strtok`(), the buffer it's deserializing. Which means that you cannot use the serialized object to deserialize two or more instances of the object, unless you make a copy of the serialized object beforehand.

It is not actually clear, from what you've shown, where the actual bug is, but it's most likely because you did not allocate a buffer that's big enough for the serialized object. Even though you believe that "it works correctly", it didn't, and ended up corrupting memory, which didn't become evident until the code tried to deserialize the corrupted buffer, resulting in undefined behavior.

But, if you do believe that your buffer was big enough, you should be able to figure out the answer yourself by using your debugger to step through the code, and examine what it's doing. For problems involving segmentation faults at runtime, the correct answer is to always use a debugger, to examine the runtime status of the application and determine the problem.

Comment: I know serialize works because I can print the array that has been serialized. All I am asking is how you call a function such as deserialize. I am not worried about how the functions work, just how I call them. As I mentioned I have not worked with classes in a while and have forgotten the basics.

Comment: It seems that you're calling them just fine. If you called them wrong, your code wouldn't get compiled in the first place. There would've been a compilation error. And just because you can print the array that has been serialized, in this context, it doesn't necessarily mean that you allocated the buffer correctly. I could easily show you a sample main() that copies something into a character buffer, prints the contents of the buffer to show that "it works", and ... then immediately segfaults upon return from main(), because the copy overran the buffer, and crapped all over the stack.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I have figured it out now thank you!